# Facebook Graph API Ad Creation: Unable to set the "Instagram account" dropdown field through API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am currently creating an ad within a Facebook campaign using the Facebook Graph API. I am making a POST to "https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/act_<Ad_Account_ID>/ads/".

Everything is working as expected, with the exception of trying to set the Instagram account field within the Identity section of the ad settings in the Facebook Ads Manager. I need to be able to set this field in order to automatically post the ad, otherwise the ad's status is "In review". The ads I am creating will not have an Instagram account attached to them and I want to set the Instagram account drop down field to "Use selected Page". The "Use selected Page" field seems to be a default option from what I can tell, however I can't seem to determine what the parameter and value I need to send in the POST would be.

I suspect that the "instagram_actor_id" may be the parameter I need to send over in the POST, but I have been unsuccessful in determining what the default value needs to be to set the Instagram account field value to "Use selected Page". Currently, the Instagram account field value is empty and I have to manually click the drop down to select the "Use selected Page" (only option as seen in the photo).

To clarify, I am not trying to connect an Instagram account, I just one to be able to set the Instagram account field to "Use selected page" via the graph API.

Facebook documentation for creating a dynamic ad (Step 4):
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/dynamic-ads/get-started#ad

Ad Creative Object Story Spec (instagram_actor_id):
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative-object-story-spec/

[Facebook Ads Manager Ad Settings After Creating Ad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vi3S2.png)

Comment: I'm struggling with the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

For pages that do not post to a specific Instagram account (i.e. when you see '**Use Selected Page**' in the Ads Manager), Facebook creates what's called a **Page-backed Instagram Account**. This account cannot be logged into and is used only to publish campaigns related to that specific page.

You can find the ID of the Instagram account connected to a specific page through a GET request to the following endpoint: https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/<PAGE_ID>/page_backed_instagram_accounts

See Facebook documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/ads-api/guides/pages-ig-account#read).

Save the ID related to that specific page and use it as the value for **instagram_actor_id**